# Firestore get QueryDocumentSnapshot from QuerySnapshot by id

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a `QuerySnapshot`, I can get a specific `QueryDocumentSnapshot` like so:

```js
db.collection("collection-name").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  const docId = "myDocId";
  const myDoc = querySnapshot.docs.find(doc => doc.id === docId);
});
```

Is there a more direct way, to avoid having to use find, for example (in pseudo code):

```js
db.collection("collection-name").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  const docId = "myDocId";
  const myDoc = querySnapshot.get(docId);
});
```

I couldn't find anything in the API ref, but it seems like a common use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing much more concise.  As you can see from the API documentation [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) doesn't provide a map-based interface to the result set.  `querySnapshot.docs` is an array, and the only way that document data is provided, so you must at least do some iteration over that array to find what you're looking for.